# Simple autoit script to toggle Caps Lock on and off in Win7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, script, autoit

I am looking for a simple autoit script that will toggle the <kbd>Caps-Lock</kbd> and/or <kbd>Num-Lock</kbd> keys on and off to stop my Windows 7 laptop going to the screensaver and locking.

These options are grayed out due to the new policies that have been rolled out by the employer.

I did try a cursor moving script I found on here, but it did not work and whenever I start using the system, the script seems to pause and I cannot get it to start again without closing the script and relaunching it.

Can anyone help someone with no coding knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be an AutoIt script? If not, [CapsLock.exe](http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/capslock/) and [NumLock.exe](http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/numlock/)  can be wrapped in the simple batch file:

```
@echo off
:: Set delay beetwen blinking lights
:: Delay = Seconds * 1000

set DELAY=5000
set SLEEP=ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w %DELAY% > NUL

:loop
capslock.exe on
%SLEEP%
capslock.exe off
%SLEEP%
numlock.exe on
%SLEEP%
numlock.exe off
%SLEEP%
goto :loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted @beatcracker 's Batch code to AutoIt:

```
Opt("SendCapslockMode", 0)

; Set delay between blinking lights
; Delay = Seconds * 1000
Local $iDelay = 5000

While 1
    Send("{CAPSLOCK on")
    Sleep($iDelay)
    Send("{CAPSLOCK off")
    Sleep($iDelay)
    Send("{NUMLOCK on")
    Sleep($iDelay)
    Send("{NUMLOCK off")
    Sleep($iDelay)
WEnd
```

If you want to check idle time (to prevent toggling if you're using your machine), take a look on [_Timer_GetIdleTime()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Timer_GetIdleTime.htm).